# Selection of elements considering features

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, select

Still here to propose you a new problem. In the image is shown my situation. In yellow are reperented the streets, in green the buildings and in red is represented the area of the building if they collapse, in function of their height, and thus the red show the possible interference of the buildings on the streets.
Now, I want to evaluate which building create and interference or not, and taking as reference some rules I have to follow, when the red area totally overcome the yellow street means that the bulding create and interference.
My problem now is to select (not manually) which building create an interference or not, how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Step 1: Formulate your task, criteria and desired outcome in a more stringent matter so other people don't have a hard time to understand it. Sorry... I really don't get it.

Comment: Maybe create a line from the opposite side of the street where the building is, if its red area touch this line, we can consider that the red area overcome the street.

Comment: @J.Monticolo that's interesting, but how can I implement it? I mean, I'm don't want to select the buildings manually, I'm searching a "systematic" way to do that

Comment: @Mark: there is maybe a better solution. For the proposed solution, the first step is to separate the left and right side of the street and for each building, with a distance algorithm tell on which side the building is for the streets it can interfere, it can be complex for example the building in the bottom right of your screenshot.

Comment: this doesn't seems too complicated no ? you just check if each designated red area of building (collapsed area) has a crosses relation with a street ... then you return the building id and the building is interfering with your streets network. But you need to clarifiy your process

Comment: I don't know a crosses relation for 2 polygon layers, so curious about this solution.

Comment: I'm not good in writing algorithms, I'm still learning so is difficult for me in this moment :))) I would like to find another solution...
In this moment I'm trying "extract by position" putting as: "extract element from: and here I select the layer red areas" and then in "respect the elements from: here I'm selecting the layer of the yellow street" (and also I'm trying with the layer of the black line) 
@J.Monticolo

Comment: and I'm setting to select the elements if the red area "touch-intersect-contain-overlaps-crosses" so I cannot consider the elements not selected because are the buildings that not interfere the street. BUT it doesn't work... 
@J.Monticolo

Comment: I cannot tag two profiles @Maximilienjaffrès but I'm considering also you

Comment: Mhh indeed no easy crosses relation for polygons ... I was thinking difference of the collapsed area and the street is a multipart + it touches a street (or geometry difference is different from raw collapsed area). It would be the best approximate of "crosses" in this case but you may have edge case ...